# How to Place text content within the <button> element or give the <input> element a value attribute

Tags: wcag

I need your help on an issue with wcag accessibility at a wordpress website, checking the website with wave it returns two basic errors "A button is empty or has no value text." for two toggles menu , the suggestion of wave to fix the error is "Place text content within the  element or give the  element a value attribute."

but I have no idea how to fix this issue the code for my toggle buttons is:

```
<button class="btn-close-form" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false"> <span></span> </button>
```

so if someone knows how to assign a text or alt text to a toggle button in order to fix this issue it will be great.

Thanks to all of you for your time!!!

Comment: between your opening button tag and closing button tag there is just an empty span element... no text describing what the button is.

Comment: Hi Zachary , thank you for your answer and your help , so should I try to insert something like input alt="text" ? , I am sorry if my asnwer seems to be stupid but I really dont know what to modify? Thank you again bro!!!!!

Comment: It says in the suggestion - "... or give the element a value attribute". <button value="some value" ...></button>

Answer (score 1):

**1** - You may add text inside and hide it in a CSS. WordPress provides special [class](https://make.wordpress.org/accessibility/handbook/markup/the-css-class-screen-reader-text/) for this - `screen-reader-text`

```
// CSS

/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  word-wrap: normal !important;
}
.screen-reader-text:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
  clip: auto !important;
  clip-path: none;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: auto;
  left: 5px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 15px 23px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 5px;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar. */
}
```

```
// button
<button class="btn-close-form" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false"> 
<span></span>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Show search modal</span> 
</button>
```

This class hides element visually from users but can be read with screen-readers. This element will be visible when focused

**2** - add [aria-label](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_to_provide_labels_for_objects) or [aria-labelledby](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-labelledby_to_provide_a_name_for_user_interface_controls) attributes

```
<button class="btn-close-form" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Show search modal"> 
<span></span>
</button>

// or
<span id="show-modal-label">Show search modal</span>

<button class="btn-close-form" data-toggle-target=".search-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-search-modal" data-set-focus=".search-modal .search-field" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="show-modal-label"> 
<span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: It worked !!!!! many many thanks bro , thank you for your time and your valuable help, In meantime I also tried to enter in function.php where the code button located something like that :<button id="toggle-button" data-toggle-target=".main-menu-modal" data-toggle-body-class="showing-main-menu-modal" aria-expanded="false" data-set-focus=".close-main-nav-toggle">
                    <span>Menu</span> <!--<?php esc_html_e( 'Menu', 'fashion-diva' ); ?>-->
                </button> it also worked but the text was not align correctly